# Trying to add Discord alerts/hooks to an existing python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So i want to monitor a webpage, and if a change occurs, i would like to be notified of that via Discord.

Searching google, i landed on this page https://www.adventuresintechland.com/detect-when-a-webpage-changes-with-python/

and it seems to work when i test it on my website. 
But i would like to add Discord alerts to this code but seem to be stuck

i have looked into Dhooks on github and have been stuck trying to implement it

```
# Hunter Thornsberry
# http://www.adventuresintechland.com

# WebChange.py
# Alerts you when a webpage has changed it's content by comparing checksums of the html.

import hashlib
import urllib2
import random
import time

# url to be scraped
url = "http://raw.adventuresintechland.com/freedom.html"

# time between checks in seconds
sleeptime = 60

def getHash():
    # random integer to select user agent
    randomint = random.randint(0,7)

    # User_Agents
    # This helps skirt a bit around servers that detect repeaded requests from the same machine.
    # This will not prevent your IP from getting banned but will help a bit by pretending to be different browsers
    # and operating systems.
    user_agents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
        'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
        'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19'
    ]

    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', user_agents[randomint])]
    response = opener.open(url)
    the_page = response.read()

    return hashlib.sha224(the_page).hexdigest()

current_hash = getHash() # Get the current hash, which is what the website is now

while 1: # Run forever
    if getHash() == current_hash: # If nothing has changed
        print "Not Changed"
    else: # If something has changed
        print "Changed"
        break
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the discord API connection: with python, use discord.py.

Have a look at the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and learn how to use it, then connect the two - just add the required discord.py imports and setup to the file in the appropriate places and add a prompt to send a message whenever the webpage changes (in this case, replacing the `print("changed")` with `yourChannel.send("webpage has changed!)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect to the discord API to send a message on event. The information can be found [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro) and [here](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs).

It is worth noting that the discord python library is currently only compatible with python 3.6, so you will have to run

```
pip install -U discord.py
```

on python version 3.6 rather than python 3.7.